# Automatically $broadcast data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to`$broadcast` some data from one controller to another using the`$rootScope` .

It appears to work fine if I use a trigger like an ng-click to run the function that will broadcast but how do it without that?

As you can see in the fiddle, I have the broadcast in a `$scope.cast` function so why is it not working if I run the function like this: `$scope.cast();` ?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kjgj7Ldz/19/

I need this because I am getting some data in the first controller and when that finishes, I want to automatically broadcast it without `ng-click`, `ng-change` or any other triggers.

Is `$broaadcast` a wrong thing to do in this scenario? If so, how can I achieve data communication between those two controllers?

Comment: its because controller 2 hasn't been created yet.

Comment: @DanielA.White So I should make a broadcast in controller2 that will announce controller1 when it's ready to receive the info? and then controller 1 will broadcast?

Comment: @Skkyp Depends on what you mean by *data communication*. Is it just a one off thing? Or need to constantly communicate? Instead of broadcasting things back and forth, maybe try to load the *consumer* first and then load the *producer*? Or maybe make use of a promise that site in some sort of a shared service?
It's hard to suggest the best solution without knowing exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid using scope for commutication between controllers by creating a simple pub-sub service that handles the communtication channel for you. For example it can deliver all messages for late subscribers. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/mz1672s0/).

```
app.service('MQ', function() {
  var listeners = [],
    messages = [];

  return {
    pub: function(message) {
      listeners.slice(0).forEach(function(listener) {
        try {
          listener(message)
        } catch (ignored) {
          console.log(ignored)
        }
      })

      // save message for late subscribers.
      messages.push(message)
    },
    sub: function(listener) {
      // deliver all messages
      messages.slice(0).forEach(function(message) {
        try {
          listener(message)
        } catch (ignored) {
          console.log(ignored)
        }
      })

      // save listener
      listeners.push(listener)

      // create unbinder
      return function() {
        listeners.splice(listeners.indexOf(listener), 1)
      }
    }
  }
})

app.controller('Controller1', ['$scope', 'MQ', function($scope, MQ) {
  MQ.pub('John Snow')

  $scope.cast = function() {
    MQ.pub(Math.random())
  }
}]);

app.controller('Controller2', ['$scope', 'MQ', function($scope, MQ) {
  var unsub = MQ.sub(function(message) {
    $scope.message = message
  })

  // clean-up bindings on scope destroy.
  $scope.$on('$destroy', unsub)
}]);
```